# How to update a pivot table with multiple relations using Eloquent in laravel 8

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

I am working with laravel 8, it causes me the doubt how to update that data from user the pivot table

class User extends Authenticatable
{

```
public function roles()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Role::class,'contracts');
}

public function offices()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Office::class,'contracts');
}

public function documents(){
    return $this->hasMany(Document::class,'creator_id');
}
```

}

There is a many-to-many relationship between roles and offices that provides me with a pivot table like so:

```
Table Name: contracts
Colums:
id
user_id
office_id
role_id.
```

And I tried this way but it only updates me the user data but in the pivot table it does nothing

```
public function update($id, UpdateUserRequest $request)
    {

        if (empty($id)) {
            return $this->sendError('User not found');
        }
        $userUpdate = User::find($id);
        $userUpdate->name = $request->name;
        $userUpdate->document = $request->document;
        $userUpdate->email = $request->email;
        if ($request->password != null) {
            $userUpdate->password = bcrypt($request->password);
        } else {
            $userUpdate->password = $userUpdate->password;
        }

        $userUpdate->save();
        $userUpdate->offices()->updateExistingPivot($request->office_id,['role_id'=>$request-                  >role_id]);

        return $this->sendResponse($userUpdate->toArray(), 'User updated successfully');
    }
```

I need to solve that problem.

Comment: Hello ... this is an English only site, can you translate your question into English?

Comment: how edit my publication ?

Comment: Your question has been reopened.

Comment: Your relationship columns don't fit. You should manually specify them